# How can I replace GPT with `jee pee tee` and not `JEE PEE TEE` in MS Word?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, find-and-replace, case-sensitivity

I have a Microsoft Word document containing:

> This document provides an overview of the GPT-3+ technology.

The Word document contains a few more occurrences of GPT.

I'd like to replace GPT with `jee pee tee` ([reason](https://github.com/neonbjb/tortoise-tts/issues/392)).

I tried:

[image]

but it replaces `GPT` with `JEE PEE TEE`. How can I replace GPT with `jee pee tee`?

I use MS Word LTSC 2021 on Win10.

---

[image]

becomes:

[image]

The font used for GPT isn't all caps:

[image]

In the search and replace, I made sure that `all caps` wasn't selected either:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One needs to check "Match case":

[image]

(Sorry I thought `Match case` was only use as a search criterion.)